# Can't start ubuntu-sdk

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, qt, ubuntu-sdk

On Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64 bit, I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then when I type:

```
ubuntu-sdk
```

I got:

> `Could not initialize GLX Abandon (core dumped)`